# What is the difference between storage media and storage devices

Tags: storage

I am having a rather distressing confusion about whether `storage media` and `storage devices` are the same terms. I found on [this yahoo answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120206233945AA4EgT2) page that there is a subtle difference but very tricky to understand.

I have googled a lot but cannot find the satisfying answer.

Can anyone kindly explain the difference between these two terms with easy-to-understand examples.

Regards

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general English vocabulary, not about technical terms of computer science.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Media is what holds the information, e.g. disk platen, CD, magnetic stripe.
Device is what uses the media and provides a physical interface.

For devices that have removable media, such as CD/DVD players the distinction is easy. For other devices where the media is an integral part of the device, the distinction is not so easy because the media is not designed to be removed, e.g. hard drive, thumb drive.

Answer (score -1):

Media is a medium on which data is saved. e.g CD
Devices are something which run a Media on it. eg CD player.